# Mapbox marker with popup on top of (polygon shape) layer with popup shows 2 popups

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

For a current project i'm using mapbox to show area's and show markers on top of those area's. Both should have a popup with a short description.

The marker is HTML + CSS and has a pop attached to it, according to the documentation here: https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers-gl-js/

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
   .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
   .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
   .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + 
      marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
   .addTo(map);
```

The area's are drawn by adding a layer with geojson object as described in this example: https://122e4e-mapbox.global.ssl.fastly.net/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/. Listening to the click events like this:

```
 map.on('click', 'states-layer', function (e) {
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.name)
        .addTo(map);
});
```

This all works fine, until a marker is positioned on top of another layer. When clicking the marker both the popup of the marker and the popup of the layer/polygon show.

**Expected Result**: To only show the popup of the marker since this is the top element clicked.

There is no `on('click')` for markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i've used the following workaround:

Create marker with custom HTML and give it a class.

Now when listening to the click event for the area popup, check if the target classList contains the marker class en return and let mapbox internally handle the marker popup.

`map.on('click', 'states-layer', function (e) {
    if (event.originalEvent.target.classList.contains(MARKER_CLASS)) return;
}`

Hope this helps if anybody encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `new mapboxgl.Popup()` each time the map is clicked, then yes, you'll get a, well, "new MapboxGL popup" :)

You need to reuse your existing popup, like this:

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup();
map.on('click', 'states-layer', function (e) {
    popup.setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.name)
        .addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: Well, by using `setPopup` the popup for a marker is handled bij mapbox internally. There is no click event for markers to listen to and handle the marker clicks like you mention above.